# Adding one part into another part in WSDL4J

Tags: java, web-services, dynamic, wsdl, wsdl4j

I am generating WSDL dynamically using WSDL4J and I am able to create a WSDL  file, but I want a nested structure (I mean, I want to declare a complex element and add it into the message).

So I want to add the `TestService` `element` into the `wsdl:message` `TestServiceRequest` dynamically using Java code and WSDL4J...

```
<element name="TestService">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="servicetag" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="header" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="requestparam" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="body" type="xsd:string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
<wsdl:message name="TestServiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestService">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In which way does it fail?

Comment: I am able to create a wsdl message and able to add part into it.but the thing is I am not able to create and add the complex element as wsdl:part into wsdl using wsdl4j.I expecting that in wsdl message,'testservice' will be one wsdl:part and 'testservice' is complex element with four simple elements.

Comment: Any library other than wsdl4j to create WSDL dynamically using Java ...